# Postgres : multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to run the below query but its throwing error ERROR: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed. Can anyone pls help what I am doing wrong here.If there are duplicates in data then it should update multiple records with same value.Any suggestion what to modify in below query will be appreciated,I am new to sql not sure what i am doing wrong here

```
UPDATE test t1 SET 
folder=t2.folder,name=t2.name,session_name=t2.session_name,
mapping_name=t2.mapping_name,
update_date=to_char(now(),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')::timestamp,is_deleted='N'
FROM stg t2 
WHERE t1.subject_id=t2.subject_id and t1.wf_id=t2.wf_id and 
t1.instance_id=t2.instance_id 
and t1.session_id=t2.session_id and t2.insert_date is null;
```

Comment: more than one rows can be matching to your where clause

Comment: yes @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV - Is there way to modify query where I can update if multiple matches exist?

Comment: Are you sure about tag postgresql ?

Comment: @ValNik - yes,I am running it on postgres

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your error: multiple updates to a row by the same query is not allowed.

Comment: not sure @Valnik even I tried to replicate on fiddle but its working fine on fiddle.https://dbfiddle.uk/RBGO_PsA however on db its not working but based on below scenario can you pls help with sample query..

Comment: As I understand it, your question is no longer about the error. Give an example of the data and the desired result.

Comment: Hi @Valnik- Its working fine with fiddle but same scenario is not working in my database,not sure why.If you can please consider the same data as present on  dbfiddle.uk/RBGO_PsA and help tweaking the query or may be split it into 2 queries i)to update duplicate records and ii) to update distinct records will be helpful. As single  query is not working so trying to see if we break it into 2 queries.One query to only update duplicate records and other query to update duplicate records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256690/discussion-between-test-and-valnik).

Comment: Try (https://dbfiddle.uk/Z_RinjXf). This works on postgresql 9.5

Comment: @Valnik-not sure but its working on fiddle but on database.Can you help with 2 queries.i) to update duplicate records ii) to update the unique records.

Answer (score 0):

See simple example.
Test data:

```
create table table1 (id int,val varchar(100),updated timestamp);
insert into table1 (id,val) values 
 (1,'Value 1')
,(2,'Value 2')
;
create table table2 (id int,val varchar(100));
insert into table2 (id,val) values 
 (1,'Value 1-1')
,(1,'Value 1-2')
;
```

Table1

| Id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 1 | Value 1 | null |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |

Table2

| Id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Value 1-1 |

Update table1:

```
update table1
set val=src.val, updated=now()
from (select distinct id,val from table2) src
where src.id=table1.id;
```

| id | val | updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Value 2 | null |
| 1 | Value 1-1 | 2024-01-26 13:31:03.61001 |
| 1 | Value 1-1 | 2024-01-26 13:31:03.61001 |

Comment: @ValNik-Thanks for explanation but its other way round my question example : if in table 1 we have same record present for value 1 with same data and in table 2 we have 1 record for value 1 then I want that same data be updated for value 1 in table 1 and for value 2 it should be populated as whatever data coming from table 2.I am able to update if there is 1 record but if there is duplicate my query is not able to handle it.If you can help with that pls.

Comment: I have edited your inputs and output for clarity .If you can help with the above scenario.